# How to avoid not empty namespace deletion with Kubernetes Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a Kubernetes project managed by Kustomized (Kubernetes). This project deploys two deployments in the same namespace.

Basically, I have the following directory structure:

```
kustomize -> app1 -> kustomization.yaml
kustomize -> app1 -> namespace.yaml
kustomize -> app1 -> app1.yaml

kustomize -> app2 -> kustomization.yaml
kustomize -> app2 -> namespace.yaml
kustomize -> app2 -> app2.yaml
```

The files `namespace.yaml` create in both the case the same namespace so that the first application deployed, create the namespace and the second reuse it. Obviously, the problem is when I try to remove only one of these applications:

```
kubectl delete -k kustomize/app1
```

remove both the applications because the namespace is removed and app2 too. An easy solution to this problem is to move `namespace.yaml` outside the folders and just call it standalone. However, this approach requires user must remember to run:

```
kubectl apply -f namespace.yaml
```

before of:

```
kubectl apply -k kustomize/app1
kubectl apply -k kustomize/app2
```

I know another possible solution is via script. My question is that exists a way to better manage namespace removal with Kustomize so that it is removed only if it is empty.

Comment: Have you tried to move `namespace.yaml` to a separate directory and just refer to that namespace in the `kustomization.yaml` ?

Comment: I don't think this change anything. When I run ```kubectl delete -k kustomize/app1``` it analyzes the kustomization.yaml and if it refers to namespace.yml it simply calls its removal that automatically remove app2. I think that if Kustomize doesn't support this feature there is anything I can do. The same problem exists on Kubernetes (without Kustomize). I hoped Kustomized addressed this issue but I think no progress has been done from this perspective.

Comment: I did not mean that you should refer to `namespace.yaml` but to the namespace it creates, e.g. with `namespace: my-namespace` See some examples on https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/

Comment: This is what I am doing right now and I describe it in the message. Now my kustomization.yaml only refer to the namespace ```namespace: mynamespace``` then outside the two folders above ```kustomize/app1``` and ```kustomize/app2```  I have a namespace ```namespace.yml``` and I run ```kubectl apply  -f namespace.yml``` before the deployments and ```kubectl delete  -f namespace.yml``` at the end. But I don't like this extra commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have this directory structure:

```
kustomize -> ns -> namespace.yaml

kustomize -> app1 -> kustomization.yaml
kustomize -> app1 -> app1.yaml

kustomize -> app2 -> kustomization.yaml
kustomize -> app2 -> app2.yaml
```

Also you can add a `kustomization.yaml` at the root, so that you only need this to apply all:

```
kubectl -k kustomize/
```

That will create the namespace and both apps.

And you can still delete only one app if you want:

```
kubectl delete -k kustomize/app1
```

And since you don't have an `namespace.yaml` in that directory, it does not delete the namespace.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds reasonable. I will try it.